# Can't Find JQuery When Running 'ng test' Command

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have created a project using new angular-cli version and I made the project up and running. When I run ng serve and ng build command it works perfectly without giving any errors. But when I tried to run ng test it shows me errors like this.

```
theme.provider.ts (53,31): Property 'removeClass' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.
theme.provider.ts (64,35): Property 'addClass' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.
theme.provider.spec.ts (7,30): Cannot find name '$'.
```

I have added JQuery in the following way to the angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
 ],
```

Then I have imported JQuery to my main module via this way

```
import 'jquery';
```

Are there any missing steps in the above configurations?

Comment: can you put the error in text not image?

Comment: Post has updated

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `@types/jquery` installed, try adding `jquery` to the list of types in `tsconfig.spec.json` (it should already have `jasmine` and `node` in the list).

---

Also, when you add `jquery.min.js` to the `scripts` list in `angular-cli.json`, it ends up in your `scripts.bundle.js`.  When you then do `import 'jquery';` in your main module it **also** ends up in your `vendor.bundle.js`, so you have added the code twice.

Instead of doing `import 'jquery';`, just add `jquery` to your `compilerOptions` types list in `tsconfig.app.json` (or create one `"types": ["jquery"]`).  You will then be able to reference the global jquery object without importing it a second time.