# Getting error while running ng test command

Tags: angular, unit-testing, user-interface, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run test cases for angular project.I am new to unit testing of UI. Whenever I try to run "ng test" command, getting following error.

```
10 01 2019 18:13:33.754:INFO [Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 7.0.0)]: Connected on so
cket 3bR__mAXbLbWIyMdAAAA with id 62613448
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 7.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:56

Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 7.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:56
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Windows 7.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/scripts.bundle.js:56
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701835/cant-find-jquery-when-running-ng-test-command

I followed above answer. Still getting same error of jquery is not defined.

Comment: An error says that you need to include jQuery in your testing dependencies

Comment: @TusharWalzade in which file exactly. I have added in package.json file,angular-cli.json.

Comment: this may help you - https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jquery